# Get string from array object in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays. And I use `filter()` to compare and bring me the value that is equal in both.

```
$(array1).filter(array2);
```

In the console the value appears like that: http://prntscr.com/bkqkd7.

How do I get the value, the string from that object. 
What does it mean the "0" in the console?

Comment: `0` is the first element of the array. Also you can see the length is `1`. So it is an array and its elements being displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it as an Array and loop through it:

```
for (var i=0; i<$(array1).filter(array2).length; ++i)
```

Comment: Great! thats It. I come up with the same solution but yours is better written. Thanks.